# Can C# recursive methods be inlined?

Tags: c#, recursion, inline, tail-recursion

Suppose I have a **recursive** method, or a static method. Can it be inlined for performance? It would probably contain a one-liner, conditional operator.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wesdyer/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c/

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla No, I am interested in inline methods, not anonymous methods.

Comment: Is the real question "does that improve performance" ?

Comment: Could you share with us the code in question?

Comment: Its a hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the fucntion does..

If it Factorial: (5!)==5*4*3*2*1 you can write it in the following ways:

```
private static int Factorial(int v)
        {
            if (v == 1)
                return v;
            return v * Factorial(v - 1);
        }
```

OR:

```
private static int Factorial2(int v)
    {
        int i = 1;
        int accum = 1;
        while (i++ < v)
            accum *= i;
        return accum;
    }
```

BUT - I'm sure not all function  are transferable like that one.
As for performance the first takes 3 mili, with n=80, and the second one took 0 mili... So yes - there's an advantage, as you assumed.

EDIT:
I saw now you placed a tag of "Tail recrusion" which, upon hovering on the tag - tells you the answer. Yes compilers know how to make these recursions to an "inline".My Time test refered to "debug" mode.. should test in release too..

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want the compiler to inline your method. Not all method can be inline. In this case, recursive method can't be inline method because it need to call itself.

> **AggressiveInlining**
>   Specifies that the method should be inlined wherever possible.

Inlining is replacing the method call by the method content, so recursive methods can't be inlined.